# What is the default feature importance for classif.randomForestSRC in mlr?

Tags: r, random-forest, mlr

#### Below is the code I used, "ano.cla.filter" is a filtering method defined by myself

```
set.seed(132541) # repeatable
lrn = makeFilterWrapper(learner = makeLearner( "classif.randomForestSRC",
                                               predict.type = "prob",
                                               ntree=100,
                                               importance="permute"),
                                               fw.method = "ano.cla.filter",
                                               fw.threshold = 0.5)
rdesc = makeResampleDesc("RepCV",folds=3L,reps=2L, stratify = TRUE,predict="both")

AllGenes_Model = resample(learner = lrn,
                          task = cli.task,
                          resampling=rdesc,
                          show.info = F,
                          models = TRUE,
                          measures = list(mlr::auc))
```

The default value for importance is FALSE when you check with getParamSet("classif.randomForestSRC"). However, I can still get values for feature importance when using getFeatureImportance.

#### Question

What is the default feature importance of classif.randomForestSR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call `getParamSet("classif.randomForestSRC")` you get the ParamSet and the defaults of what would be a new learner object.
However, in your example you constructed the learner with `importance="permute"` so this is what will be calculated.
In consequence, if you call `getFeatureImportance()` on a model inside the resample result you will obtain the feature importance values determined by the underlying learner.
In contrast, you cannot obtain the filter values after resampling that easily.
You can only obtain the features that have been selected.

I give you an example that works out of the box with mlr:

```
library(mlr)
lrn = makeLearner( 
  "classif.randomForestSRC",
  predict.type = "prob",
  ntree=100,
  importance="permute")
lrn_w = makeFilterWrapper(
  learner = lrn,
  fw.method = "variance",
  fw.perc = 0.9)
rdesc = makeResampleDesc("RepCV",folds=3L,reps=2L, stratify = TRUE,predict="both")

res = resample(
  learner = lrn_w,
  task = sonar.task,
  resampling=rdesc,
  show.info = F,
  models = TRUE,
  measures = list(mlr::auc))

# gets the feature importance of the first model has them
getFeatureImportance(res$models[[1]]) 
# because we used a wrapper, in this case it is the underlying model that has them
getFeatureImportance(res$models[[1]]$learner.model$next.model)

#FeatureImportance:
#Task: Sonar-example
#
#Learner: classif.randomForestSRC
#Measure: NA
#Contrast: NA
#Aggregation: function (x)  x
#Replace: NA
#Number of Monte-Carlo iterations: NA
#Local: FALSE
## A tibble: 6 x 2
#  variable importance
#  <chr>         <dbl>
#1 V1        -0.00297 
#2 V2         0.000741
#3 V3        -0.00144 
#4 V4         0.00294 
#5 V5        -0.00292 
#6 V6        -0.00365 

# however, the filtered features are given by the FilterWrapperModel
getFilteredFeatures(res$models[[1]])
#[1] "V1"  "V2"  "V3"  "V4" ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To get the feature importance. I need to use getFeatureImportance(res\$models[[1]])  with lrn and getFeatureImportance(res\$models[[1]]\$learner.model\$next.model) with lrn_w. right? Is this importance calculated on OOB data? What if I want to calculate the feature importance on the test dataset? The last question is still about the default feature importance. The default value for the hyperparameter "importance" from  
 "classif.randomForestSRC" is FALSE. Why can I still get feature importance values? What do those values represent?

Comment: BTW, can I use your code to re-edit my question?

Comment: 1) No, you don't have to write `$learner.model$next.model` because `getFeatureImportance` tries to find the nested model that has feature importance values.
2) You would have to check the documentation of `randomForestSRC`.
3) I don't know
4) Well, you changed the hyperparameter.
5) Yes. You can use my code.